# Why does my value (from custom fields) get override by old value (from said fields)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to have the value from 2 custom fields that the user put in through My Account/Edit-Address shown in the same custom fields but in checkout, right now it gets override by old (input) values even though the field (seen through browser inspector) has the new value. How do I stop this?

I'm fairly new to both woocommerce, plugin-making and wordpress. Right now I've not really tried much that made any difference (put the code in different order, changed up the priorities, changed names... As you see, I don't really know what I'm doing).

This is how I made the fields:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'plugin_add_custom_billing_fields' );
function plugin_add_custom_billing_fields($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_org_number'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Organisationsnummer', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => __('T.ex. 1234-5678', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_org_reference'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Kostnadsställe/referens', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => __('T.ex. Per Olofsson', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

This is how I save the fields:

```
function reigel_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta( $customer_id, $posted ) {
    var_dump($customer_id, $posted);
    if (isset($posted['billing_org_number'])) {
        $dob = sanitize_text_field( $posted['billing_org_number'] );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_org_number', $dob);
    }

    if (isset($posted['billing_org_reference'])) {
        $dob = sanitize_text_field( $posted['billing_org_reference'] );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_org_reference', $dob);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_user_meta', 'reigel_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 10, 2 );
```

As you see, I've been searching through StackOverflow before and got some help from Reigel! Tell me if you need any more code.

The results I want: My value (from database) to be shown in Checkout after edited in My Account/Edit-Address.

Actual results: The old value is shown in Checkout, the new in My Account/Edit-Address.

**EDIT:** Seems like the plugin for Klarna Checkout is messing up with sessions.

**EDIT 2:** Yes, it was Klarna. I'll push this problem for a later time because the team discussed and opted to remove the plugin instead.